# SharePoint 2010 InfoPath & Workflow. "The file is checked out for editing by"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I'm working in a sharepoint 2010 workflow with an infopath form. When I check in my dev machine, the workflow and form are working fine. But when I deploy it to the production server I get an error in the second step when I'm trying to submit the InfoPath form, the error says "The file '[url_of_the_file]' is checked out for editing by '[user]'". I have all the versioning settings off for that library.

It seems that when I modify the item in the workflow, it somehow is getting checked out and then the user that has the second step gets this error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Juan Escobar.

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is an Action called "Checkin Item" in SharePoint Workflow, you can try to insert the action before you make any changes to your current item.